# Подскажите, пожалуйста, является сложным или простым предложение?

Tags: сложное-предложение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является сложным или простым предложение:

**Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — должно быть, хочет зажечь огонь.**

Answer (score 2):

Это простое предложение; вот его схема: подлежащее + сказуемое + сказуемое. Сказуемые однородны, *должно быть* не влияет на сложность предложения.

Sharon верно заметила, что запятой, а по-хорошему и тире, здесь быть не должно:

Бабушка уже топчется около стола, должно быть хочет зажечь огонь.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, как объяснить знаки препинания в  простом предложении с однородными сказуемыми (возможно, вопрос связан с непониманием пунктуации в этом предложении): 1) почему ставится запятая и тире между однородными членами; 2) В Правилах ПАС указано, что вводное слово не обособляется от однородного члена, например:.Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.);§ 94 http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126#pp126

Comment: @Sharon спасибо, я обновил ответ.